# Error on second level object for nodejs response

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, undefined, response

I have this situation.., I'm making something like this:

```
app.post('someUrl', function (req, res) {

    var r = res.data;

    var a = {};
    a.name = r.name || "",
    a.someotherKey : {
        id: r.otherKey.id || ""
    }

});
```

the thing is that when res.data == "", I can assign the value of a.name because r.name is "undefined", but I for r.otherKey.id I get an horrible

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
```

any ideas to solve the problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `&&` operator to do:

```
a.someotherKey = {
    id: r.otherKey && r.otherKey.id || ""
}
```

`&&` will return the second value if both are true, and `false` if one (or both) is false.

Comment: that's an elegant solution, but what would it happen on  a 5 level object!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specifically useful for if you have a deep object, say `r.otherKey.prop.furtherDown.id`.

You could use a `try {} catch {}` block to just do it, and handle the error if it's undefined:

```
try {
    a.someOtherKey.prop.furtherDown = {
        id: r.otherKey.prop.furtherDown.id || ""
    };
} catch (e) {
    a.someOtherKey.prop.furtherDown = {
        id: ""
    };
}
```